# Как забрать значение из input и вывести в html с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Начал изучать JavaScript, сейчас тренируюсь писать код, но почему-то никак не получается написать то, что хочу. Гугл особо не помог, возможно не там ищу.
У меня есть форма с input-ами name, surname. Допустим я делаю галерею с формой. Я хочу, чтобы человек, вписывая свои имя и фамилию, нажимал на кнопку и попадал на следующую страницу, где в div или span выводились бы его Имя и Фамилия с приветствием (Приветствуем, Иван Иванович!). Сейчас для меня не важно, будет ли отправляться в базу данные с формы или не будут (PHP и mySQL ещё не учил), просто хочу сделать то, что не получается. Мне не хватает практики, кто что знает, посоветуйте, может есть какой-нибудь ресурс. Где можно потренировать чистый JS? Возможно можно как-то на jQuery сделать такое. Ниже прикреплю мой код, надеюсь на помощь.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- Этот код на первой странице -->
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
  <button id="next" hraf="2 страница">Далее</button>
 </div>
   
   <!-- Этот код на второй странице -->
  <div>
  <p>Приветствуем, <span id="theName">...</span> <span id="theSurname">...</span>!</p>
 </div>

 <script>

 // Забираем значение из input
 var theName = document.getElementsById("name")[0]; //забрали имя
 var val1 = theName.value;
 var theSurname = document.getElementsById("surname")[0]; //забрали фамилию
 var val2 = theSurname.value;
 // Отдаём значение в span (html)
 var output1 = val1;
 document.getElementById("theName").innerHTML = output1; //отдали имя
 var output2 = val2;
 document.getElementById("theSurname").innerHTML = output2; //отдали фамилию

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Есть такое понятие как веб сайт на одной странице. Это позволяет менять содержимое на экране без перехода к новому html-файлу. В Вашем случае, сначала должна быть показана первая часть элементов html страницы, а остальное - скрыто. После ввода имени форма ввода должна быть скрыта или даже удалена, а остальные элементы- показаны, с уже прописанные введенным именем

Comment: То есть JavaScript работает в пределах только одной страницы?

Comment: Да, js работает в пределах одной страницы